# How to remove new lines and tabs from text?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like

```
"this is line 1\n\t\n\t\tthis is line 2\n\n\n\t\tthis is line 3\t\t\tthis is line 4"
```

What I want to do is remove repeated specific characters ("\n", "\t") from this text.

Expected result;

```
"this is line 1\n\tthis is line 2\n\tthis is line 3\tthis is line 4"
```

I have below regex but it only removes repeated characters.

```
String text = text.replaceAll("([\n\t])\\1+", "$1");
```

Is there any regex for this?

**EDIT:** for example there is a text like

```
"\n\t\tHELLOWORLD\t\t\n\n\n\t"
```

What I want to get is;

```
"\n\tHELLOWORLD\t\n"
```

Comment: Can you show expected string result? Or is the second code example supposed to be one?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes second text is the expected result.

Comment: you should double the backslashes `"([\\n\\t])\\1+"`

Comment: @anubhava no it doesn't work.

Comment: How should `foo\t\n\tbar` be handled?

Comment: @Pshemo like "foo\t\nbar".

Comment: What is the logic behind it? Can you explain/show your reasoning? Why not `foo\n\tbar`?

Comment: @Pshemo from left to right first char is "\t" then start with \t

Comment: I am trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish. For now it looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you really trying to solve (why do you need this regex/code)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution;

First remove all duplicate characters with first regex. After that replace consecutive texts.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    text= text.replaceAll("([\n\t])\\1+", "$1");
    text= text.replaceAll("\n\t\n", "\n\t");
}
```